# Removing duplicated JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

So I am able to successfully extract data out of my JSON object, the issue that I am having is that the data is being quadruplicated. Can someone tell me why that is happening? I have never seen this before. Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData, function(data){
        var channelHTML = ''
        jQuery.each(data, function(i){
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.results) {
            channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].call_mine_status + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].cdr_source + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].tracking_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].external_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="' + data.results[i].file_url + '">Recorded Call</a></td></tr>';
            }
        });
        jQuery('#conv_table').append(channelHTML);
    });              
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/cmw3co4s/1/)

Comment: You have to do `jQuery('#conv_table').empty()` before `append()`

Comment: You are having 2 loops `each` and `for` both check https://jsfiddle.net/cmw3co4s/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having 2 loops `each` and `for` both check

```
var channelHTML = ''
            for (var i in data.results) {
            channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].call_mine_status + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].cdr_source + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].tracking_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].external_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="' + data.results[i].file_url + '">Recorded Call</a></td></tr>';
            }
            jQuery('#conv_table').append(channelHTML);
        });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmw3co4s/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two loops for the same thing, remove

> `for (var i in data.results)` this loop and modify `jQuery.each(data, function(i)` by `jQuery.each(data.results, function(i)`.

The Code will work perfectly and it will not repeat.

Here is the fiddle link [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cmw3co4s/5/)